# Putting points on each vertex of a graph (plot)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to put points at each vertex of this graph but I don't know how to do it, would you have an idea?
[image]
Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

members = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/members.csv")

expeditions = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/expeditions.csv")

success = members[members["success"]==True]
success = success.reset_index()
plt.figure(figsize=(17,8))
success_saisons = success.drop(success[(success["season"]=="Unknown")].index)
success_saisons.groupby("season")['success'].count().plot(linewidth=6)
plt.title("Répartition des succès en fonction des saisons",fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel("nombre de membres ayant réussi", fontsize = 12)
```

Comment: can you add the expected output?

Comment: I would like to have points on the summits

Comment: I added a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to plot the vertex you can specify the marker size and shape using matplotlib marker and markersize arguments.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

members = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/members.csv")

expeditions = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/expeditions.csv")

success = members[members["success"]==True]
success = success.reset_index()
plt.figure(figsize=(17,8))
success_saisons = success.drop(success[(success["season"]=="Unknown")].index)
success_saisons.groupby("season")['success'].count().plot(linewidth=6, marker="o", markersize=12)
plt.title("Répartition des succès en fonction des saisons",fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel("nombre de membres ayant réussi", fontsize = 12)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you so much, this is exactly what I wanted to do !

Comment: Your welcome, i understood after reading your comment :)